# Slow SQL query (has_many through)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am facing a slow query on our production machine.

Following Setup:

the join model (polymorphic)

```
# Table name: util_participants
#
#  id                  :bigint           not null, primary key
#  assignable_type     :string           not null
#  assignable_id       :bigint           not null
#  contact_id          :bigint
#
# Indexes
#
#  assignable_index        (assignable_id,assignable_type)
#
# Foreign Keys
#
#  fk_rails_...  (contact_id => client_contacts.id)
```

This class is for assigning contacts to different elements, like a documentation (assignable).

One query i have is

```
documentation.contacts
>  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "client_contacts" INNER JOIN "util_participants" ON "client_contacts"."id" = "util_participants"."contact_id" WHERE "client_contacts"."account_id" = $1 AND "util_participants"."assignable_id" = $2 AND "util_participants"."assignable_type" = $3
```

account is for multi-tenancy
For a specific element i have a query time of 7 seconds. But i cannot track down the cause. If i switch the account_id to another customer, i get fast execution time.

For example

```
SELECT count(*) 
 FROM client_contacts 
 INNER JOIN util_participants 
 ON client_contacts.id = util_participants.contact_id 
 WHERE client_contacts.account_id = 35 
    AND util_participants.assignable_id = 1;
```

is very slow.

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM client_contacts 
INNER JOIN util_participants 
ON client_contacts.id = util_participants.contact_id 
WHERE client_contacts.account_id = 27 
  AND util_participants.assignable_id = 1;
```

is not but 27 has even more contact rows.

EXPLAIN of postgres results in

```
 Aggregate  (cost=3688.79..3688.80 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..3688.79 rows=1 width=0)
       Join Filter: (client_contacts.id = util_participants.contact_id)
       ->  Index Scan using index_client_contacts_on_account_id_and_client_id on client_contacts  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=8)
             Index Cond: (account_id = 35)
       ->  Seq Scan on util_participants  (cost=0.00..3680.48 rows=1 width=8)
           Filter: (assignable_id = 1)
(7 rows)
```

Total row count for participants is 130k and contacts 6500

Update:

Here the output for

slow one:

```
> EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) SELECT count(*) FROM client_contacts INNER JOIN util_participants ON client_contacts.id = util_participants.contact_id WHERE client_contacts.account_id = 35 AND util_participants.assignable_id = 1;

 Aggregate  (cost=3688.79..3688.80 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=6991.704..6991.706 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*)
   Buffers: shared hit=893735
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..3688.79 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=6991.699..6991.700 rows=0 loops=1)
         Join Filter: (client_contacts.id = util_participants.contact_id)
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 428
         Buffers: shared hit=893735
         ->  Index Scan using index_client_contacts_on_account_id_and_client_id on public.client_contacts  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.015..1.160 rows=428 loops=1)
               Output: ....
               Index Cond: (client_contacts.account_id = 35)
               Buffers: shared hit=71
         ->  Seq Scan on public.util_participants (cost=0.00..3680.48 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..16.325 rows=1 loops=428)
               Output: ....
               Filter: (util_participants.assignable_id = 1)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 127268
               Buffers: shared hit=893664
 Planning Time: 0.183 ms
 Execution Time: 6991.741 ms
```

fast one (different account_id)

```
EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) SELECT count(*) FROM client_contacts INNER JOIN util_participants ON client_contacts.id = util_participants.contact_id WHERE client_contacts.account_id = 33 AND util_participants.assignable_id = 1;


 Aggregate  (cost=3688.79..3688.80 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=16.882..16.884 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*)
   Buffers: shared hit=2088
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..3688.78 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=16.876..16.878 rows=0 loops=1)
         Inner Unique: true
         Buffers: shared hit=2088
         ->  Seq Scan on public.util_participants  (cost=0.00..3680.48 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.007..16.873 rows=1 loops=1)
               Output: ...
               Filter: (util_participants.assignable_id = 1)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 127268
               Buffers: shared hit=2088
         ->  Index Scan using client_contacts_pkey on public.client_contacts  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
               Output: ...
               Index Cond: (client_contacts.id = util_participants.contact_id)
               Filter: (client_contacts.account_id = 33)
 Planning Time: 0.176 ms
 Execution Time: 16.923 ms
```

Why the different query plans for almost the same query?

Comment: Step one will be to ANALYZE these tables, and then to use EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for this statement. That shows you the plan, but also the results from this plan. This shows where the time is spent and can give you an idea about how to optimize.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, i updated my post with a more detailed query plan.

Comment: The JOIN is on contact_id, but there is no index for this one. How does the query plan and execution change when you create an index on this column?

Comment: After an `ANALYZE` on both tables, the query-plan is fast now. Its using the second plan i posted above. Not sure if this is a long-term solution.

Comment: Long term solution is an index on util_participants.contact_id

Comment: By the way, your fast query still spends 16.8 milliseconds out of 16.9 milliseconds on an obsolete sequential scan. This query can be much faster when using an index scan, but you have to create the index first.